# Why shouldn't I use lasers or lightsabers if I have Light Powers?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, lasers

In this world,these humans have the ability to control energy.Specifically, to transport energy someplace else And/or converting it.

Someone can have a very good range of where this ability goes.And some focus more on precision.

This character has the ability to convert existing energy intl light.

My problem is that light saber or light swords or lasers are overused when it comes to light weapons.

The questions are
A) What would be an acceptable reason as to why he doesn't use lasers/light sabers

B) What would be a better non-overused light weapon

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: Hi Adamm, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. In an effort toward getting your question reopened and and answer you can use, are you looking for a new kind of "light weapon" or are you looking for a way to define your superpower? You might read the *[Wheel of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wheel_of_Time)* books by Robert Jordan. He had all kinds of trinkets that enhanced, manipulated, and even stored the "power" of his "magic users."